# Inverse Score in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [54, 74, 71, 78, 12]})
```

Expected output,

```
value    score
 54    scaled value
 74    scaled value
 71    scaled value
 78     50.000
 12     600.00
```

I want to assign a score between 50 and 600 to all, but lowest value must have a highest score. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Could you add an example of the expected output?

Comment: I added expected output, thanks.

Comment: @EgemenZeytinci any hints on how the calculation is being done?

Comment: Score of lowest value must be 600. And highest value's score must be 50. No special calculation method.

Comment: It appears that you are applying an additional rule to the calculation of the score. Can you please check that and share it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve, maybe you could provide the exact expected output for this input.
But if I understand well, maybe you could try

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [54, 74, 71, 78, 12]})
min = pd.DataFrame.min(df).value
max = pd.DataFrame.max(df).value

step = 550 / (max - min)
df['score'] = 600 - (df['value']-min) * step

print(df)
```

This will output

```
   value       score
0     54  250.000000
1     74   83.333333
2     71  108.333333
3     78   50.000000
4     12  600.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my idea. But I think you have a scale on your scores that is missing in your questions.

```
dfmin   = df.min()[0]
dfmax   = df.max()[0]
dfrange = dfmax - dfmin
score_value = (600-50)/dfrange
df.loc[:,'score'] = np.where(df['value'] == dfmin, 600, 
                             np.where(df.value == dfmax, 
                                      50, 
                                      600 - ((df.value - dfmin)* (1/score_value))))
df
```

that produces:

```
   value   score
0     54  594.96
1     74  592.56
2     71  592.92
3     78   50.00
4     12  600.00
```

Not matching your output, because of the missing scale.